# Configure Jetty with maven-plugin (goal run-forked) override resourceBases

Tags: java, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I'm trying to execute Jetty(9.2.4.v20141103) trough maven-plugin, with multiple resourceBases. I have debugged de code, and seems that QuickConfiguration class overrides the configured resourceBases with this code:

```
  public void preConfigure(WebAppContext context)
    throws Exception
  {
    String war = context.getWar();
    if ((war == null) || (war.length() <= 0)) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("No location for webapp");
    }
    resolveTempDirectory(context);

    Resource webApp = context.newResource(war);
    if (webApp.getAlias() != null)
    {
      LOG.debug(webApp + " anti-aliased to " + webApp.getAlias(), new Object[0]);
      webApp = context.newResource(webApp.getAlias());
    }
    if ((!webApp.exists()) || (!webApp.isDirectory()) || (webApp.toString().startsWith("jar:"))) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Webapp does not exist or is not unpacked");
    }
    context.setBaseResource(webApp);

    LOG.debug("webapp={}", new Object[] { webApp });

    Resource quickStartWebXml = getQuickStartWebXml(context);
    LOG.debug("quickStartWebXml={}", new Object[] { quickStartWebXml });

    context.getMetaData().setWebXml(quickStartWebXml);
  }
```

The line `context.setBaseResource(webApp)` overrides the configured resourceBases with the webapp directory.

It only fails with the `run-forked` goal, `run` goal works nice.

```
        <plugin>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>9.2.4.v20141103</version>
              <configuration>
                <!--                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>-->
                <webApp>             
                  <defaultsDescriptor>D:\desarrollo\herramientas\servidores\jetty-distribution-9.2.4.v20141103\webdefault.xml</defaultsDescriptor>


                </webApp>

<jvmArgs> -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.LEVEL=INFO -Xmx1024m -Xms512m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=6001,server=y,suspend=y</jvmArgs>
<maxStartupLines>10000</maxStartupLines>

<contextXml>D:\desarrollo\herramientas\servidores\jetty-distribution-9.2.4.v20141103\jetty-hcepro-web.xml</contextXml>
              </configuration>
              <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
                  <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
                  <version>${commons-dbcp.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>com.informix.jdbc</groupId>
                  <artifactId>ifxjdbc</artifactId>
                  <version>${informix.driver.version}</version>
                  <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>
              </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

My contextXml File:

```
<Configure id="wac" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="contextPath">/shop</Set>

    <!-- to avoid checking for jsp-->
    <Call name="setAttribute">
      <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.WebInfIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
      <Arg>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</Arg>
    </Call>
    <Call name="setAttribute">
      <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
      <Arg>zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</Arg>
    </Call>
    <New id="staticResources" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.resource.ResourceCollection">
        <Arg>
            <Array type="java.lang.String">
                <Item>D:\Project\view\src\main\webapp</Item>
                <Item>D:\Project\core\web\src\main\resources\META-INF\resources</Item>
                <Item>D:\Project\modules\shop\front\src\main\resources\META-INF\resources</Item>
                <!-- More directories-->

            </Array>
        </Arg>
    </New>      

     <Set name="baseResource">
        <Ref refid="staticResources"></Ref>
     </Set>
     <!-- Database Stuff-->
```

I also tried to include resourceBases inside pom.xml, but nothing changed. Debugging the code it seems it loads the directories right, but after that, it executes QuickConfiguration preConfigure method and overrides the base resource with the webapp dir.

¿any help?

Comment: Why are you trying to use multiple resource bases? (the jetty-maven-plugin needs to configure the resources bases itself to pull content in from the multiple locations being reported by the maven subsystem, including all of the locations reported by the various plugins in use by your build, otherwise your webapp isn't valid to be started)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I' sorry, I don't get you. I need multiple resource bases because the project is composed from several maven subprojects, that have their own static resources (likes html, js and css). It's absolutely independent from the build process. And as I explain, the goal jetty:run works like charm. It's only the goal jetty:run-forked, that seems to use the QuickConfiguration class, that overrides my resourcebase configuration.

Comment: You are fighting a setting that jetty-maven-plugin wants to control fully.  Why not just bundle the html, js, and css as standard Servlet resource jars `WEB-INF/*.jar!/META-INF/resources/` instead?